# Simple javascript method issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand the different between the following codes..

```
Select.prototype.create = function(){

codes1......

}

Search.prototype.create = function(){

codes2......
}
```

They both have different codes but the same method. I am not sure why and how it works. Can anyone helps me about it? Thanks alot.

Comment: One creates it on `Select`, one on `Search`?

Comment: Why all the negative votes on this? The OP has a misunderstanding and has tried to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript functions/methods are not unique by the name only. The whole definition, Search.prototype.create, should be unique.  *I say should be because Javascript allows you to replace definitions without causing any errors/warnings*

Javascript sees two methods, one on the Search prototype chain, and the other on the Select prototype. These two methods just happen to be called the same but are unrelated according to the language.

Often, in any other language or API, there are common names used like `length, toString, call, dispose, replace` and the list could go on.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same methods defined on prototype of of two different constructors. Select and Search appear to be constructors for different objects (as implied by their name). If you did

var a = new Select();
a.create(); // this will run codes1 ....

var b = new Search();
b.create();  // this will run codes2 ...